# Java - having trouble with making threads perform one after another

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to the idea of using threads and am having quite a bit of trouble with them. The method call displayComplexStimulus(phase1Trial.getComplexStimulus()) displays a set of jlabels (the phase1CompoundLabels), that contain images, on the screen.

What I am trying to do is get that set of jlabels to display for two seconds and then disappear. When I don't include the code that instantiates, runs and joins the compoundThread thread and alternativesThread thread, the images display fine. However, when I include the code that instantiates, runs and joins the two threads, the images never even appear, when I am trying to get the jlabels to appear for two seconds before disappearing.

Am I correct that the problem is that the alternativesThread is not waiting until the compoundThread has finished executing before it starts its execution? I am confused about why this is the case, given that I have joined the two threads. If someone could help me understand why my code doesn't work as intended it would be appreciated.

```
public void phase1() {

    while (totalNoOfPhase1Trials > 399) {
        Phase1Trial phase1Trial = new Phase1Trial(numberOfElements, elementColors);

        displayComplexStimulus(phase1Trial.getComplexStimulus());
        validate();


        Thread compoundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }

        });

        Thread alternativesThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
                    remove(phase1CompoundLabels[i]);
                }
                validate();
            }
        });

        compoundThread.start();
        alternativesThread.start();


        try {
            compoundThread.join();
            alternativesThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        totalNoOfPhase1Trials--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. `alternativeThread` isn't waiting for `compoundThread` to finish executing. One way (I'm pretty sure this is not a good way) could be to use a while loop or something to block while `compoundThread` is alive. A better way would be to do a form of callback. In your case, the try-catch block could have a finally, which could spawn the 'alternativeThread'.

Comment: If you want two pieces of code to run sequentially, you only need one thread.

Comment: Debosmit - I instantiated the alternativesThread in a while loop (with the condition that while the compoundThread is alive it does not execute), and it only partially fixed my problem, as now the images display but they do not disappear after two seconds.

Comment: Kevin - Don't I have to use two threads, as I only want one block of code to execute after a two second pause (which I thought would be only possible by creating two threads and making the first thread sleep for two seconds before the second thread executes).

Comment: For what you are doing over here, I completely support what @KevinKrumwiede is saying. You need one thread. You need the second thread to run after the first one. So, why even make a second thread. Just do the work after the first one!

Comment: Debosmit, I tried that initially, by just creating a thread and making it sleep for two seconds, but the two second delay would not occur and the code afterwards just executed immediately.

Comment: I never understand these questions. If you want sequential execution *why are you using threads?*

Comment: Because I was reading that if you want your program to pause for an interval, the Thread's sleep() method was good for doing that.

Comment: @lb91 I don't know whether you think that's an answer to my question, but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run `alternativesThread`  after completion of `compoundThread`  then please write `alternativesThread.start();` inside the run() method of `compoundThread` So, it will wait till the processing of `compoundThread`  completes.

Comment: What you mean is, to start the new thread at the end of the `run()` method.

Comment: That would mean that I have to make the alternativesThread thread declared globally, right?